# gitlab: How to trigger specific CI/CD from a page/wiki/link? (i.e. based on variables from the link)

Tags: ansible, continuous-integration, gitlab

we are using gitlab for  CI/CD which trigger ansible playbooks to deploy stuff accordingly. But we want to give flexibility to end-user , so they can trigger deployment for specific objects from a wiki or a page or link. So basically, we don't want CI/CD to run everytime when code is checked-in, but ONLY when user trigger something from a page.

Let's say my page/wiki/link is something like..

```
https://selfhosted_gitlab/myproject/location_USA/panel_green.wiki
https://selfhosted_gitlab/myproject/location_EU/panel_blue.wiki
```

And was thinking to provide a LINK or button within the above wiki, so when the user clicks on it, and should trigger the playbook to deploy the code to deploy relevant objects.
For example when user triggers the `panel_green`,  it should trigger Ansible playbook with parameter of `panel=green location=USA`,so it triggers accordingly

Comment: That sounds like a fine approach; what have you tried so far and what error is it producing for you?

Comment: I've been able to do all workflow like CI/CD triggering different stages, environment etc. Also can trigger specific ansible playbooks etc. But still not able to figure out how to pass values from a page/wiki/payload towards the ansible from gitlab. 
Currently, i'm doing a workaround by asking updating end-user to update a file and save it and the backend "grep" for what they have updated and triggers it. Bit ugly, but wanted to give flexibility to click on a link or a button, so can be triggered from anywhere